# How can i list authors with their book count, including those who have 0 books?

Tags: sql

I've got a few tasks, to help me practice SQL and I ran into some trouble

I've got 2 Tables in my DB -> authors(authorId, Name) and books(bookId, authorId, title).

So first part of my task was to get authors together with their book count, so i've done this:

```
SELECT authors.name, COUNT(*) AS 'number of books' FROM authors, books WHERE authors.authorId=books.authorId GROUP BY authors.name;
```

Now I need to display authors with their book count, including authors who have zero books, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `Left join`

```
SELECT authors.name, sum(case when bookId is null then 0 else 1 end) AS 'number of books' FROM authors
left join books on authors.authorId=books.authorId 
GROUP BY authors.name;
```

Comment: weird thing happens when I do this - it lists all 7 authors and says that they all have 1 book each, even though author with Id 3 has no books at all.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT authors.Robert John Recchio, COUNT(*) AS 'number of books' FROM authors, books WHERE authors.authorId=books.aut
horId GROUP BY authors.name;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).